# Getting an image from a search query

Tags: php, image, search

I feel my question is simple, but it seems like the solution is tricky.

For a simple personal project I am building my own japanese Vocab Trainer and for every english word, I want to display a picture with the japanese vocab.

The website is build in PHP and REST for getting the vocabs and audio files, but adding an image from a search result is not as straight forward as I thought.
I don't care about the engine or the method. I just want a simple picture for my keyword/vocab.

I tried google custom search api, but with no luck.. or let me say, I lost motivation. Is it really necessary to go all the way with the api, for such a simple thing?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How many vocab words do you have? You may want to hand pick images and add each vocab word with an image assigned to it in a database. If you use a google search it will be inconsistent and might not actually be an accurate depiction of the word.

Comment: yeah, I am not so concerned about the accuracy. It's a list of approx 10.000 vocabs, so I am not really keen on picking them myself by hand. I want it to be a hit or miss. If it helps me learn the vocab - cool. if not - not.